# Concatenate string to the_field()

Tags: php

I need to show something like "40 MINUTES PREP/COOK" and the preparation_time returns "X MINUTES" but I can't concatenate a string to the_field.

```
<?php if(the_field( 'preparation_time' )) :
    the_field('preparation_time');
    echo " PREP/COOK";
endif; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to show more of the relevant code, but, to begin with, if you want to check for the availability of a 'preparation_time' ACF value, use

```
if ( get_field( 'preparation_time' ) ) : // get_field(), not the_field()
```

As the ACF docs put it, `the_field( 'field' )` is the same as `echo get_field( 'field' )` - so wouldn't return true or false, but instead simply print (if you get to it).

I'd probably write it

```
if ( get_field( 'preparation_time' ) ) {
    echo get_field( 'preparation_time' ) . 
        ' 40 MINUTES PREP/COOK' ;
}
```

But no guarantees, since I don't know the context.